# How to send all the values of a dynamic input field to the action page and `echo` an `Ordered List` with the values?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, jquery-ui

In my form, I have made a dynamic text input field using `jQuery` and made it sortable using `jQuery-UI`. But the problem it, when I submit the form, only the last value of the form is sent to the action page.

How can I send all the values to the form action page and `echo` an `Ordered List` with the values?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions. Here is the snippet of the dynamic form:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var fixHelperModified = function(e, div) {
             var $originals = div.children();
             var $helper = div.clone();
             $helper.children().each(function(index) {
                $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
             });
             return $helper;
          },
          updateIndex = function() {
             $('div.index').each(function(i) {
                $(this).html(i + 1);
             });
          };
       $("#add").sortable({
          helper: fixHelperModified,
          stop: updateIndex
       }).disableSelection();
       $("#addNew").click(function() {
          $('#add').append("<div class='row rem' id='move'><div class='col-md-1 index'>1. </div><div class='col-md-9'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='members'></div><div class='col-md-1'><button class='delete btn btn-warning btn-xs'>Delete</button></div></div>");
          updateIndex();
       });
       $("body").on('click', '#add .delete', function() {
          $(this).closest(".rem").remove();
          updateIndex();
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="members" class="form-horizontal" action="pritnPreview.php">
   <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label class="form-name">Members</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
               <div id='add'>
                  <div class='row rem' id='move'>
                     <div class='col-md-1 index'>1. </div>
                     <div class='col-md-9'>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' name='members'>
                     </div>
                     <div class='col-md-1'>
                        <button class='delete btn btn-warning btn-xs'>Delete</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                     <button id='addNew' type="button" href="#">Add another</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" name="submitSave" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

The `printPreview.php` page:

```
<?php 
    if (!empty($_POST['cc'])) echo 'CC: ' . $cc; 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the input to `cc[]` to save a array of values

```
 name='cc[]'
```